# Joomsocial errors in joomla 2.5.9

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, social-networking, joomla-extensions

I have installed joomla 2.5.9 and joomsocial 2.8.

But I have two problems:

1. I have this text in administration panel:

   > Strict Standards: Non-static method JFTP::getInstance() should not be called statically in /home/public_html/joomla/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php on line 409
2. joomsocial toolbar is not working good or as demo.Tthe sub menu for profile and friends doesn't appear when hovering the button.

Comment: You should really discuss this on Jomsocial forum. To suppress the error message change error displaying settings in backend and/or disable debugging mode

Comment: i already did but they did`nt replay :(